# Get method name from soap service call

Tags: php, soap

I have a working soap service with several methods available. I am wondering if it is possible to get the name of the method that the user contacting the service is requesting; for example:

```
try{
    $soapServer = new Zend_Soap_Server('http://path-to-service/wsdl');
    $soapServer->setClass('My\Soap\Server\Class');
    $soapServer->handle();

    // is something like this available? :
    // $callName = $soapServer->getLastRequestedMethod();
    // or
    // $callName = $soapServer->getMethod();
}catch(SoapFault $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I didn't see anything like this in the docs @ zend or php.net, but just thought I would check to see if anyone knows a way to do this; would be useful for logging purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Soap_Server` supports a `getLastRequest()` method.  Example usage would be:

```
$soapServer = new Zend_Soap_Server('http://path-to-service/wsdl');
$soapServer->setClass('My\Soap\Server\Class');
$soapServer->handle();
$lastRequestXML = $soapServer->getlastRequest()`;
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about going this route, but it means I will have to parse the xml string and look for some kind of identifier. Not ideally what I was looking for, but what I will probably end up doing. Thanks